# Filtering by categorical and numerical variables in R

Tags: r

I have a very large dataset I am working with in which I wish to impute the median into missing values in all continuous variables and fill "Not Available" into all categorical.

```
data[ ,sapply(data, is.numeric)]

data[ ,sapply(data, is.character)]
```

I am using these functions to determine which is which, but I don't know how to use them to do what I want. Any help is appreciated into this process.

Comment: In base R, you assign to the subset, e.g `data[is.na(data[ ,sapply(data, is.numeric)]) ,sapply(data, is.numeric)] <- sapply(data[ ,sapply(data, is.numeric)], median)`, or in dplyr, `data %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(coalesce(., median(.)))) %>% mutate_if(is.character, coalesce, 'Not Available')`. That said, I'm not sure imputation is wise here. Regardless, you should really add some sample data to make your example [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#5963610), though.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will work. I'm not sure if there is a more efficient way to do this though.

```
library(data.table)

dt = data.table(continuous = c(rnorm(5), NA), categorical = c(LETTERS[1:5],NA))

> dt
    continuous categorical
1:  0.77044982           A
2:  0.12955447           B
3: -0.03965276           C
4:  1.59332441           D
5:  0.21909899           E
6:          NA          NA

fixColumns = function(x){
  if(class(x) %in% c("factor", "character")){
    if(any(is.na(x))){
      x[is.na(x)] = "Not Available"
      return(x)
    }else{
      return(x)
    }
  }else{
    if(any(is.na(x))){
      x[is.na(x)] = median(x, na.rm = TRUE)
      return(x)
    }else{
      return(x)
    }
  }
}

dt = dt[ , lapply(.SD, fixColumns)]

> dt
    continuous   categorical
1:  0.77044982             A
2:  0.12955447             B
3: -0.03965276             C
4:  1.59332441             D
5:  0.21909899             E
6:  0.21909899 Not Available
```